# Grouping results "fairly" using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of **system users** that are awaiting to be assigned with an **account**.
The assignment algorithm is very simple, assigning should be as fair as possible which means that if I have 40 accounts and 20 system users I need to assign 2 accounts per system user.
If I have 41 accounts and 20 system users I need to assign 2 accounts per system user and split the remaining accounts between the system users again (in this case, one system user will be assigned with one extra account).
I am trying to figure out how to do this while using a LINQ query.
So far I figured that grouping should be involved and my query is the following:

```
from account in accounts
    let accountsPerSystemUser = accounts.Count / systemUsers.Count
    let leftover = accounts.Count % systemUsers.Count
    from systemUser in systemUsers
        group account by systemUser into accountsGroup
select accountsGroup
```

However I am uncertain how to proceed from here.
I am positive that I am missing a where clause here that will prevent grouping if you reached the maximum amount of accounts to be assigned to a system user.
How do I implement the query correctly so that the grouping will know how much to assign?

Comment: Seriously drop the LINQ (at least halfway through) and write an old fashioned loop. I bet you can you do that. So do it. It works, it's not unreadable, and it's not slower.

Comment: @MartinhoFernandes: I prefer to learn how it's done correctly using LINQ and it shouldn't be **that** hard.

Comment: Something similar: [MoreLinq/Batch.cs](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation that works if you can restrict yourself to a `IList<T>` for the `accounts` (you can always use `ToList` though).

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TBucket, TSource>> DistributeBy<TSource, TBucket>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IList<TBucket> buckets)
{
    var tagged = source.Select((item,i) => new {item, tag = i % buckets.Count});
    var grouped = from t in tagged
                  group t.item by buckets[t.tag];
    return grouped;
}

// ...
var accountsGrouped = accounts.DistributeBy(systemUsers);
```

Basically this grabs each account's index and "tags" each with the remainder of integer division of that index by the number of system users. These tags are the indices of the system users they will belong to. Then it just groups them by the system user at that index.

This ensures your fairness requirement because the remainder will cycle between zero and one minus the number of system users.

```
0 % 20 = 0
1 % 20 = 1
2 % 20 = 2
...
19 % 20 = 19
20 % 20 = 0
21 % 21 = 1
22 % 22 = 2
...
39 % 20 = 19
40 % 20 = 0
```

Comment: So my buckets should be the account and the source should be the system users? Can you explain how this works and why does it split fairly (that is if I have 41 accounts and 20 system users, how does everyone gets assigned with 2 accounts except the first (or random, doesn't matter here) that is assigned with 3 accounts?

Comment: I believe that it should be the other way around. I need to split the accounts per system user, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @the_drow: oh, sorry, I misunderstood. But it works the same. I just need to flip the two around.

Comment: @MartinhoFernandes: How come you're the only one with a simple implementation here? Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: @the_drow: as I mentioned this simple implementation has the restriction that you need a `IList<SystemUser>`. It doesn't work with a pair of `IEnumerable<T>`s. That's why it's simple: I have access to an indexer (`buckets[t.tag]`). Using only `IEnumerable<T>`s gets complicated, and that's why I advised you to use an old-fashioned loop.

Comment: I have tested this and it works and works well and fits my needs. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MartinhoFernandes: Won't it work on arrays as well? It just needs random access, right?

Comment: @the_drow: sure, random access is enough. And with arrays it works already as is because arrays implement `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using "pure LINQ" (i.e. using query comprehension syntax), and to be honest LINQ probably isn't the best approach here. Nonetheless, here's an example of how you might do it:

```
var listB = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
var listA = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };

var groupings = (from b in listB.Select((b, i) => new
                                        {
                                            Index = i,
                                            Element = b
                                        })
                 group b.Element by b.Index % listA.Count).Zip(listA, (bs, a) => new
                                                                      {
                                                                          A = a,
                                                                          Bs = bs
                                                                      });

foreach (var item in groupings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.A, string.Join(",", item.Bs));
}
```

This outputs:

```
1: a,d
2: b,e
3: c
```

Comment: Could you mark where the account is and where the system user is according to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't thin "pure" LINQ is really suited to solve this problem. Nevertheless here is a solution that only requires two `IEnumerable`:

```
var users = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var accounts = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var accountsPerUser = accounts.Count()/users.Count();
var leftover = accounts.Count()%users.Count();
var assignments = users
  .Select((u, i) => new {
    User = u,
    AccountsToAssign = accountsPerUser + (i < leftover ? 1 : 0),
    AccountsAlreadyAssigned =
      (accountsPerUser + 1)*(i < leftover ? i : leftover)
      + accountsPerUser*(i < leftover ? 0 : i - leftover)
  })
  .Select(x => new {
    x.User,
    Accounts = accounts
      .Skip(x.AccountsAlreadyAssigned)
      .Take(x.AccountsToAssign)
  });
```

To cut down on the text I use the term `User` instead of `SystemUser`.

The idea is quite simple. The first `leftover` users are assigned `accountsPerUser + 1` from `accounts`. The remaining users are only assigned `accountsPerUser`.

The first `Select` uses the overload that provides an index to compute these values:

```
User | Index | AccountsAlreadyAssigned | AccountsToAssign
-----+-------+-------------------------+-----------------
A    | 0     | 0                       | 3
B    | 1     | 3                       | 3
C    | 1     | 6                       | 2
```

The second `Select` uses these values to `Skip` and `Take` the correct numbers from `accounts`.

If you want to you can "merge" the two `Select` statements and replace the `AccountsAlreadyAssigned` and `AccountsToAssign` with the expressions used to compute them. However, that will make the query really hard to understand.

Here is a "non-LINQ" alternative. It is based on `IList` but could easily be converted to `IEnumerable`. Or instead of returning the assignments as tuples it could perform the assignments inside the loop.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<T, IList<U>>> AssignEvenly<T, U>(IList<T> targetItems, IList<U> sourceItems) {
  var fraction = sourceItems.Count/targetItems.Count;
  var remainder = sourceItems.Count%targetItems.Count;
  var sourceIndex = 0;
  for (var targetIndex = 0; targetIndex < targetItems.Count; ++targetIndex) {
    var itemsToAssign = fraction + (targetIndex < remainder ? 1 : 0);
    yield return Tuple.Create(
      targetItems[targetIndex],
      (IList<U>) sourceItems.Skip(sourceIndex).Take(itemsToAssign).ToList()
    );
    sourceIndex += itemsToAssign;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this implementation does? Also you have an error near x.User. Shouldn't it be SystemUser = x.User?

Comment: @the_drow: I have tested the code and it compiles and runs using .NET 4 on my computer. However you can (re)name the property by replacing `x.User` with `SystemUser = x.User` in the last `Select` if you want to.

Comment: And what is the advantages of this method over the others suggested here? Also, why do you think LINQ doesn't fit here? After all this is a query.

Comment: @the_drow: I don't think this method is better than the other methods suggested here. I is just different. The query isn't particular easy to understand and switching to a `foreach` may improve the readability of the code.