# How to create unit tests for a fair distribution algorithm?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I have the following algorithm:
Given a list of **accounts**, I have to divide them fairly between **system users**.
Now, in order to ease the workload on the users I have to split them over days.
So, if an account has **service orders** they must be inserted to the list that will be distributed over 547 days (a year and a half). If an account has no **service orders** they must be inserted to the list that will be distributed over 45 days (a month and a half).
I am using the following LINQ extension from [a question I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660819/grouping-results-fairly-using-linq):

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TBucket, TSource>> DistributeBy<TSource, TBucket>(
this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IList<TBucket> buckets)
{
    var tagged = source.Select((item,i) => new {item, tag = i % buckets.Count});
    var grouped = from t in tagged
                  group t.item by buckets[t.tag];
    return grouped;
}
```

and I can guarantee that it works.
My problem is that I don't really know how to unit test all those cases.
I might have 5 users and 2 accounts which might not be enough to be split over a year and a half or even a month and a half.
I might have exactly 547 accounts and 547 system users so each account will be handled by each system user each day.
Basically I don't know what kind of datasets I should create, because it seems that there are too many options, and what should I assert on because I have no idea how the distribution will be.

Answer (score 2):

Start with boundary conditions (natural limits on the input of the method) and any known corner cases (places where the method behaves in an unexpected manner and you need special code to account for this).

For example:

- How does the method behave when there are zero accounts?
- Zero users?
- Exactly one account and user
- 547 accounts and 547 users

It sounds like you already know a lot of the expected boundary conditions here. The corner cases will be harder to think of initially, but you will probably have hit some of them as you developed the method. They will also naturally come through manual testing - each time you find a bug this a new necessary test.

Once you have tested bounday conditons and corner cases you should also look at a "fair" sample of other situations - like your 5 users and 2 accounts example. You can't (or at least, arguably don't need to) test all possible inputs into the method, but you can test a representative sample of inputs, for things like uneven division of accounts.

Comment: The problem is that I can't tell what the output will be. For two calls the output might be the same but it might be completely different. Say I have two accounts A and B, I also have two system users John and Bob. Without even considering if they have service orders or not the distribution is fair whenever either John is assigned with account A and Bob with account B and vice versa. So how can I check something that isn't idempotent?

Comment: @the_drow I was going to ask about that but then I'd looked at the algorithm and it had appeared deterministic. Does it actually need to be non-deterministic? That is, is the randomness a business requirement? If it must be random, can you possible mock the randomizer, allowing the behaviour of the method itself to be isolated from the randomness?

Comment: @the_drow though I'm still struggling to see how two calls with identical inputs will not give the same output.

Comment: @DavidHall: This is not a business requirement as far as I am concerned. However a unit test should not care for implementation details, only expected results. It might be valid compromise to allow the test to break if some randomness is introduced though. How can you tell that the algorithm is deterministic?

Comment: @the_drow well it just looks deterministic - there doesn't seem to be any part of the code that would behave differently given the same inputs. The mod of the index by the count should not change, nor should the grouping. Seems to me that you should easily be able to know expected results for any given input (if only by running them through the method and seeing what comes out!).

Comment: @DavidHall: But the order isn't deterministic. Arguably in a unit test I can control the input and than it will be deterministic. Hmmm... If I'll provide a sample dataset and the API could you sketch me the flow of the unit test?

Comment: @the_drow you always control the input in a unit test, that is very much the point. You ensure that a given unit of code behaves as expected for given inputs. If different order of inputs creates different outputs then this suggests that you may need a second unit test. Though not necessarily. You don't need to test all possible inputs into a method - just the interesting ones.

Comment: @the_drow For example, if you had a function which returned the sum of two integers, you might want to test inputs like (0,0) (0,1) (1,2) perhaps negatives, perhaps larger numbers but you have to recognise the point where new inputs are no longer interesting. Is testing (2,5) and (3,5) really adding value. Also - going back to your comment about implementation details - I would at least partially disagree. If considering implementation details of a method allows for better tests, then do it. For exzamp

Comment: @the_drow (sorry, accidental enter key press) for example, you need to consider implementation details to be able to mock dependencies. Also, sometimes there are implementation details that need to be tested, such as conditional branches, that you might miss by trying to restrain yourself to just thinking of inputs and outputs.

Comment: All this talk about whether the assignment is deterministic or not is a hint that there's an implicit concept waiting to be discovered and made explicit. Perhaps as an IAssignmentStrategy which can be injected into the SUT.

Comment: @MarkSeemann: Actually you might be correct. I need to think more about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your issue is that your code describes how you are solving your problem, but not what problem you are trying to solve. Your current implementation is deterministic and gives you an answer, but you could easily swap it with another "fair allocator", which would give you an answer that would differ in the details (maybe different users would be allocated different accounts), but satisfy the same requirements (allocation is fair).
One approach would be to focus on what "fairness" means. Rather than checking the exact output of your current implementation, maybe reframe it so that at a high level, it looks like:

```
public interface IAllocator
{ IAllocation Solve(IEnumerable<User> users, IEnumerable<Account> accounts); }
```

and write tests which verify not the specific implementation of accounts to users, but that the allocation is fair, to be defined - something along "every user should have the same number of accounts allocated, plus or minus one". Defining what fair is, or what the exact goal of your algorithm is, should help you identify the corner cases of interest. Working off a higher-level objective (the allocation should be fair, and not the specific allocation) should allow you to easily swap implementations and verify whether the allocator is doing its job.